# Kingsport Bill and Lyndon

Tags: diablo-iii

I have the achievement "To Catch A Thief" and I've been reading that the only way to get the "Kingsport Bill" lore is to speak to Lyndon about his origins and it will give it to me the lore. Obviously I have discussed his origins as I have the achievement, why didn't I get the Bill?

Answer (score 2):

You need to talk "Lyndon's Origins" when he is not your current merc. So.. you hire ench or templar, then talk with him.